# How do I loop through 2d arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how to loop through a 2d array horizontally vertically, diagonally and sub diagonally  to see if the array is equal to a char.if the array is equal to the char then a `bool` should return true, but my problem is the `bool` randomly returns true. the `bool` only returns true if the char is equal to array at a certain column and row. Here i am hard coding it in but i want to do it with for loops.
Let me know if you need any more info or if something needs to be explained

```
if (mCard[0][0] == '*' && mCard[0][1] == '*'&& mCard[0][2] == '*'&& mCard[0][3] == '*' && mCard[0][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[1][0] == '*' && mCard[1][1] == '*'&& mCard[1][2] == '*'&& mCard[1][3] == '*' && mCard[1][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[2][0] == '*' && mCard[2][1] == '*'&& mCard[2][2] == '*'&& mCard[2][3] == '*' && mCard[2][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[3][0] == '*' && mCard[3][1] == '*'&& mCard[3][2] == '*'&& mCard[3][3] == '*' && mCard[3][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[4][0] == '*' && mCard[4][1] == '*'&& mCard[4][2] == '*'&& mCard[4][3] == '*' && mCard[4][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}


if (mCard[0][0] == '*' && mCard[1][0] == '*'&& mCard[2][0] == '*'&& mCard[3][0] == '*' && mCard[4][0] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[0][1] == '*' && mCard[1][1] == '*'&& mCard[2][1] == '*'&& mCard[3][1] == '*' && mCard[4][1] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[0][2] == '*' && mCard[1][2] == '*'&& mCard[2][2] == '*'&& mCard[3][2] == '*' && mCard[4][2] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[0][3] == '*' && mCard[1][3] == '*'&& mCard[2][3] == '*'&& mCard[3][3] == '*' && mCard[4][3] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
if (mCard[0][4] == '*' && mCard[1][4] == '*'&& mCard[2][4] == '*'&& mCard[3][4] == '*' && mCard[4][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}

// checking for daigonal
if (mCard[0][0] == '*' && mCard[1][1] == '*'&& mCard[2][2] == '*'&& mCard[3][3] == '*' && mCard[4][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
// checking for sub diagonal
if (mCard[4][0] == '*' && mCard[3][1] == '*'&& mCard[2][2] == '*'&& mCard[1][3] == '*' && mCard[0][4] == '*') {

    CheckBingo = true;
}
```

here I tried using for loops but it does `int` always return true if the array is equal to the char.

```
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        if(mCard[row][col] == '*') {
            CheckBingo = true;
        }
        else {
            CheckBingo = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        if(mCard[col][row] == '*') {
            CheckBingo = true;
        }
        else {
            CheckBingo = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative would be to store the board as bits in a 32-bit int  (using 25 of the bits), and then you can test a bitmask for each row etc. to check.  This will actually lead to simpler code; you can have an array of the masks to check.   
 Even if you want to keep your current board array it's probably better to convert to a bitboard and use this approach . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mCard[col][row]
> ...
> ```

`row` and `col` have to be flipped.

You then start the loop assuming that match is set. If one of the cells is not matched, then match is false. See example below.

Make sure the values are initialized.

```
int main()
{
    char mCard[5][5] = {
    '*','x','*','*','*',
    '*','*','*','*','*',
    '*','*','*','*','*',
    '*','*','x','*','*',
    '*','*','*','*','*',
    };

    bool CheckBingo = true;
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        CheckBingo = true;
        for(int col = 0; col < 5 && CheckBingo; col++)
        {
            if(mCard[row][col] != '*')
                CheckBingo = false;
        }
        if(CheckBingo)
            cout << "bingo on row " << row << "\n";
    }

    bool match = true;
    for(int row = 0; row < 5 && match; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 5 && match; col++)
            if(mCard[row][col] != '*')
                match = false;
    if(match) cout << "bingo for all lines\n";

    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 && match; i++)
        if(mCard[i][i] != '*')
            match = false;
    if(match) cout << "top-left to bottom-right match\n";

    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 && match; i++)
        if(mCard[i][4-i] != '*')
            match = false;
    if(match) cout << "top-right to bottom-left match\n";

    return 0;
}
```